# Adding dynamic styles to text using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How do I add styles dynamically to a text at a specific position using angular without using innerHTML, Jquery or dom manipulation ?

For eg. `Hello World` I wanted to display like **Hello** *World*

`Hello` Should be `bold` & `World` should be in `italic`.

So Below is what I"m thinking of,

```
let text = 'Hello World'
let style = {word:'Hello',type:'bold',word:'World',type:'italic'}
```

So based on the `style` input, `text` should automatically get style based on it's type.

Is it possible to do in Angular without dom manipulation ?

Please guide me.

Comment: HTML is designed to allow us to style elements, not individual string parts inside of an element. So, the solution is to ensure each word you want to style is inside an element that is an in-line type. Most use `<span>` tags for this purpose. then, as others have suggested, use `ngStyle` or `ngClass` to style the individual `<span>`tags.

Comment: Yes I kind of looking for this... But How I put the <span> tag inside the string without innerHTML or dom manipulation ? is der any Directive available to achieve this ?

Comment: Well, there is an Angular attribute directive for `[innerHTML]`, but I'm unclear on why you don't want to use that. You would not be manipulating the DOM, Angular would be. This attribute directive is used quite extensively. Can you clarify why this isn't an option?

Answer (score 0):

You can define style in css using classes and utilise the `ngClass` directive to add classes to the element conditionally.

Comment: I wanted to add styles for a specific world dynamically. for static text I could add ngClass but for dynamic text how is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the font-style property to make it italic.
[font-style docs](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-style.asp)

Use the font-weight property to make it bold.
[font weight docs](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp)

Use ngStyle as others have suggested.
[ngStyle docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

It would look something like this:

```
.style1 {
    font-weight: bold;

}

.style2 {
    font-style: italic;

}

<div>
    <span [ngStyle]="{'style1': condition}">Hello</span><span [ngStyle]="{'style2': condition}">World</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You style each word differently by putting each one in their own span element.